# Accessing object variable via double dollar sign

Tags: php, class-variables, dollar-sign

I'm building a class in order to get variables form another php files conveniently.

Problem is that I'm using double dollar sign in order to get create $variable_name => $$varible_real_value styled hashmap and i want all iterator attributes to be class variables. Defining new variable in __constructor scope might overwrite variables from files. Problematic piece of code is

```
foreach($this->args AS $this->iterator) {
    $this->data->$this->iterator = $$this->iterator;
}
```

But when i replace it with

```
foreach($this->args AS $var) {
    $this->data->$var = $$var;
}
```

Variable '$var' will be overwritten.

```
class DataFile {

private
    $data = null,
    $iterator = null,
    $args = null
;

public function __construct($file) {
    require($file);
    unset($file);
    $this->args = func_get_args();
    array_shift($this->args);
    $this->data = new ArrayObject();
        foreach($this->args AS $this->iterator) {
            $this->data->$this->iterator = $$this->iterator;
        }    
}

public function __get($key) {
    return $this->data->$key;
}

}
```

Example usage:

```
$conf = new DataFile('mysql.php', 'var');
$databaseName = $conf->var->database;
```

Is there any workaround for this,

Thank you

Comment: `$this->data->$this` o_O You probably meant `$this->data->{$this->iterator}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$this->data->$this->iterator` is ambiguous. Do you mean the property of `$this->data` that has the name of `$this->iterator` or the `iterator` property of `$this->data->$this`?

You need to make it unambiguous:

```
$this->data->{$this->iterator}
```

The same goes for `$$this->iterator`.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for. Did't know that {} will work with double dollar sign: ${$this->iterator};